# RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu on transormer

Tags: python, tensorflow, runtime

```
def nopeak_mask(size, opt):
    np_mask = np.triu(np.ones((1, size, size)),k=1).astype('uint8')
    np_mask =Variable(torch.from_numpy(np_mask) == 0)
    if opt.device == 0:
      np_mask = np_mask.cuda()
    return np_mask

def create_masks(src, trg, opt):

    src_mask = (src != opt.src_pad).unsqueeze(-2)

    if trg is not None:
        trg_mask = (trg != opt.trg_pad).unsqueeze(-2)
        size = trg.size(1) # get seq_len for matrix
        np_mask = nopeak_mask(size, opt)
        #if trg.is_cuda:
        #    np_mask.cuda()
        print(np_mask)
        print(trg_mask)
        trg_mask = trg_mask & np_mask

    else:
        trg_mask = None
    return src_mask, trg_mask
```

This code has a problem
in this line `trg_mask = trg_mask & np_mask`
I check two tensor I am sure in different  device
the [source code can be found here](https://github.com/SamLynnEvans/Transformer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this the problem
I move the src, trg to cuda before call the create_masks function
in traning file line 30 I change:

```
 src = batch.src.transpose(0,1).cuda()
        trg = batch.trg.transpose(0,1).cuda()
        trg_input = trg[:, :-1]
        src_mask, trg_mask = create_masks(src, trg_input, opt)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like trg_mask and np_mask are tensors stored on two different devices (cpu and cuda:0). If you want to perform an operation on them, they will need to both be on either cpu or they will both need to be on cuda:0.

Based on the information given I'm not sure which variable is on which device, but if you want to move a variable from cuda:0 to cpu you can do this.

```py
var = var.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

Comment: np_mask on Cuda and trg_mask  on CPU. if I want to move trg_mask   to Cuda gave me a new problem: the input and output must in the same device. this code was working in the past but now not work. can the problem in the version of PyTorch?

Comment: I used var = var.detach().cpu().numpy() but is still in cuda

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue because of one line:

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if args.cuda else "cpu")
```

---

This can be resolved by using either:

```
device = torch.device("cpu")
```

or

```
device = torch.device("cuda")
```